# Adicionar registro em um arquivo em Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou com problema na implementação de um código em Python responsável pela manipulação em arquivos. Como faço uma função que adiciona um registro no arquivo?

```
class Professor:
    professor = 'Professor'

    def __init__(self, codigo=None, nome=None, sexo=None, idade=None, 
    area=None, telefone=None):

        self.codigo = codigo[0:3]
        self.nome = nome[0:30] 
        self.sexo = sexo[0:1]
        self.idade = idade[0:2]
        self.area = area[0:30]
        self.telefone = telefone[0:14]
```

Answer (score -3):

Usas a função open() em modo 'append' para abrir o ficheiro e acresencentar o registo.

```
    def save(self):
        with open('arquivo.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(self.codigo + ',' + self.nome + ',' + self.sexo + ',' + self.idade + ',' + self.area + ',' + self.telefone)
```